# What is "Z generic mana"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

According to the [MtG wiki](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Numbers_and_symbols), the symbol [image: {Z}] is a "Generic mana symbol", specifically representing

> Generic mana in costs that only can be paid with mana from a source that can produce two or more colors of mana.

However, I can't find any reference to it in the Standard Rules, and I've never seen or heard of it before.

Where does this symbol come from? What cards does it appear on? And what does it mean, exactly?

Comment: Here you can look up all cards with {Z} in their mana costs: https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=mana%3A%7BZ%7D and all cards with mana cost {Z} in their card text: https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=oracle%3A%7BZ%7D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is exactly one card with the {Z} symbol: [The Ultimate Nightmare of Wizards of the Coast® Customer Service](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThe%20Ultimate%20Nightmare%20of%20Wizards%20of%20the%20Coast%c2%ae%20Customer%20Service%5d).  It is a silver bordered card from Unglued, and is not legal in regular play.  On this card, Z functions exactly the same way X normally does, and the different letter merely serves to distinguish it from the X and Y already present on the card.

The wiki description comes from [Experiment Five](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bExperiment%20Five%5d) a "playtest card" from the recent Mystery Boosters.  These are not real cards and were not intended for actual play (even more so than the silver bordered cards, which were intended for play, just not *regular* play)

As to what it means, it means exactly what it says.  The playtest cards have no actual rules support.  All interactions have to be interpreted by players from the cards themselves.

Comment: As a kind of explanation, some time before Unglued the Oracle text of Fireball was changed to have cost {R}{X}{Y} and text to the effect of roughly "deal X damage divided evenly between Y+1 targets".

It was printed that way at least in the "Beatdown Box Set" (https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=26621) and apparently confused many players who (apparently) called the Wizard Customer Service. So the Ultimate Nightmare was created to mock that, by introducing an additional {Z} cost on top of {X} and {Y}.